# Vertical Menu Fixed active class

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a page with a vertical menu on the side that links to section elements on the page. what I'm trying to do is give the `li` an 'active' class when the element is scrolled to as well as when the top of section reaches the top of the page.

all this works fine - however, the last section element on the page never reaches the top so the class active remains on the previous element.

How can I make the last element a class active when scrolled to?

the menu:

```
<ul class="program-list">
<li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-toddlers">Toddlers</li>
<li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-elementry">Elementry</li>
<li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-preschool">Preschool</li>
<li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-adults">Adults</li>
</ul>
```

the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                    var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                    var programTop = jQuery('#programs').offset().top;
                    if(scrollTop >= programTop) {jQuery('ul.program-list li').removeClass('active');} 

                    var toddlersTop = jQuery('#toddlers').offset().top - 10;
                    var elementryTop = jQuery('#elementry').offset().top - 10;
                    var preschoolTop = jQuery('#preschool').offset().top - 10;
                    var adultsTop = jQuery('#adults').offset().top - 10;

                    if(scrollTop >= toddlersTop) {jQuery('ul.program-list li').removeClass('active'); jQuery('li.menu-item-toddlers').addClass('active');}
                    if(scrollTop >= elementryTop){jQuery('ul.program-list li').removeClass('active'); jQuery('li.menu-item-elementry').addClass('active');}
                    if(scrollTop >= preschoolTop){jQuery('ul.program-list li').removeClass('active'); jQuery('li.menu-item-preschool').addClass('active');}
                    if(scrollTop >= adultsTop){jQuery('ul.program-list li').removeClass('active'); jQuery('li.menu-item-adults').addClass('active');}
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I wanna be able to have the 'active' class on the bottom element even though it hasn't reached the top

Comment: Maybe you can easily check if you reached the document end and in this case highlight last your menu element, e.g.: `if (window.height + window.scrollTop == document.height) { // highlight my last element }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code sets `adults` to active, when you scroll the page to the end:

```
if (scrollTop == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height())
    {jQuery('ul.program-list li').removeClass('active'); jQuery('li.menu-item-adults').addClass('active');}
```

Answer (score 0):

optionally you may try putting something at bottom (a bottom margin may work) or

```
//html
    <ul class="program-list">
    <li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-toddlers">Toddlers</li>
    <li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-elementry">Elementry</li>
    <li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-preschool">Preschool</li>
    <li class="program-list program-menu-item menu-item-adults">Adults</li>
    <li class="menu-item-x"></li>    
    </ul>



//css
    .menu-item-x
    {
    list-style-type:none;
    }
```